# VueJS get computed properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to calculate a sum of `computed` properties that starts with `calculateSum` string.

I'm not sure how to do that since I can't get their names using `this.computed`

So my method/attempt is:

```
getSubTotal(){
    var computed_names = [];
    var computed_names_filtered = computed_names.filter(x => {return x.startsWith('calculateSum')})
    return _.sum(computed_names_filtered.map(x => eval(x+'()'))
}
```

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could access them dynamically using `this['computed_name']` using [bracket accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)
since the component instance is an object :

```
var computed_names = Object.keys(this);
var computed_names_filtered = 
computed_names.filter(x => {return x.startsWith('calculateSum')})
 _.sum(computed_names_filtered.map(x => this[x]))
```

Note that the computed property is called without `()`, but if you want to call a method you could do `this['method_name']()`

Example:

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    op1() {
      return 1;
    },
    op2() {
      return 2;
    },
    op3() {
      return 23;
    },
    total() {
      return ['op1', 'op2', 'op3'].map(o => this[o]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr, 0)

    }
  },
   
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  {{total}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you to get the list of the computeds:

```
this.$options.computed
```